Serverless function error, Winston mkdir ./logs
While trying to upload my app to Vercel to run with their server I get error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir './logs'
at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1391:3)
at File._createLogDirIfNotExist (/var/task/vercel/path0/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/file.js:761:10)
at new File (/var/task/vercel/path0/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/file.js:94:28)
at file:///var/task/vercel/path0/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/db.js:14:5
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:195:25)
at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24)
at async Server.init (file:///var/task/vercel/path0/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2875:24)
at async file:///var/task/vercel/path0/.svelte-kit/vercel-tmp/index.js:10:1 {
errno: -2,
syscall: 'mkdir',
code: 'ENOENT',
path: './logs'
}
Node.js process exited with exit status: 1. The logs above can help with debugging the issue.
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 845.59 ms    Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError

I tried to upload the ./logs folder thinking that would resolve but that doesn't appear to resolve the issue. As I didn't initially add Winston to the project I'm in the dark about the settings that may be causing this if anything.
I will attempt disabling Winston but that would take a while as logger is used in almost every function.
I have attempted now moving the log files to base directory and logging there instead

Moving the logs out to the base directory resolved the issue with mkdir ./logs.
But if anyone can explain additionally why using file./logs would cause problem in Vercel? It works fine locally.

Serverless and edge functions can execute on any number of different machines. Hence you should not rely on any local files. They usually will disappear when the instance shuts down again.
